# Gradle task to only execute uiTests

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso

I've got this Android, with the default Gradle-tasks. In the Android-project, there is a `androidTest` package, containing `integrationTests` and `uiTests`. I have also two Kotlin classes containing a suite of test classes to be called.

However, `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` runs both `integrationTests` and `uiTests`, I want to separate this. I came up with multiple solutions:

1. Android Studio's run configurations. However, this isn't checked into VCS, therefore we have no access on our Jenkins build server.
2. Add Gradle tasks in the Groovy language, however, it's not encouraged to call another gradle task in a new task.

So I'm looking for a way to only test either `integrationTests` or `uiTests`. How can I do this?

Comment: Why not run `uiTests` directly? Sorry, I'm not that familiar with Android builds. Also, why do you say it's not encouraged to call another Gradle task in a new task? In what way? It's encouraged to have Gradle tasks _depend_ on one another.

Comment: I don't want to run the whole androidTest suite, but one of the two parts of it. So depending on them isn't right.

And that's the thing, I'm looking for a way to test integrationTests OR uiTests separate from each other.

Comment: So `uiTests` and `integrationTests` are not Gradle tasks, correct? They're just two categories of test?

Comment: Correct! They're separate tests, within the test module `androidTest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to give you a cheap and cheerful answer now. Maybe someone else will be able to provide a fuller one.

Since all the tests appear to be part of the same source set, you need to distinguish between them some other way. The most appropriate solution is whatever mechanism your testing library has for *grouping*, which you can then [utilise from Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_grouping).

Alternatively, use something like a naming convention to distinguish between UI tests and integration tests.

What you do then depends on how you want the build to deal with these different categories. The main options include:

1. Using [test filtering](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_filtering) from the command line — via the `--tests` option — to run just integration or UI tests. Note that filtering only works via class name, so you'd have to go with the naming convention approach.
2. Configure the appropriate `Test` task — is that `connectedAndroidTest`? — so that if you set a particular project property it will run either the integration tests or the UI tests based on the value of that project property. This involves using an `if` condition in the configuration. This approach works with both filtering and grouping.
3. Add two extra `Test` tasks, one that executes the integration tests and one that executes the UI tests. You would leave `connectedAndroidTest` untouched. This is my preferred approach, but requires a bit more code than the others.

This answer is missing a lot of detail on how to implement those solutions, but I'm afraid filling that detail out is too time-consuming for me right now. As I said, hopefully someone will come along with a fuller answer.